# to create n number of threads and join it to main thread and monitor their status in ruby

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I have a task, which is right now a def of a controller. I want to create n number of threads depending on the number of inputs from user. 
how to create dynamic number of threads and join and monitor them at main thread in ruby?

def validate_save

```
upload_thread =[]

@counter = 1
params.each do |param_name,param_value|

    if param_name.include? "file"



        Rails.logger.debug("making a thread")
        Rails.logger.debug(@counter)
        Rails.logger.debug(param_name)
        Rails.logger.debug(param_value)
        Rails.logger.debug(param_value.original_filename)

        upload_thread << Thread.new(@counter) do
            sleep 1
            Rails.logger.debug("inside Thread:")
            Rails.logger.debug(@counter)
            if S3.upload_file(param_value)
            Rails.logger.debug('we can save into S3')
            #flash[:successful]="Successfully Uploaded :  "+params[:file].original_filename
            else
            #flash[:unsuccessful]="UnSuccessful Upload of :  "+params[:file].original_filename
            Rails.logger.debug('can not save into S3')
            end

        end

    @counter = @counter + 1
    end

end


upload_thread.each do |up_th|

    up_th.join


end
```

Comment: Too vague to answer. What do you mean by "monitor"? What should the threads be doing? How specifically is the number of threads a result of "number of inputs from user"? You can spawn a bunch of threads with `threads = 1000.times { Thread.new }`, but it's as vague an answer as your question is as a question.

Comment: I am using each thread to upload a file , number will depend on number of file browsed by user

Comment: w.r.t to my recent edit, is there a way to delegate this task to another class like we do in java

Comment: For joining them all, you can use `ThreadWait.all_waits(*upload_thread)`. As for "delegate" question, you can always subclass `Thread`, but it is not as commonly done in Ruby; `Thread.new(@counter) { |counter| UploadHandler.new(counter).run }` would be my suggested approach.